# How to obtain picture tag that is situated in another tag in XML file with python

Tags: python, xml, tags

I try to parse a large xml file with Python, but when I want to print pictures information, there are nothing, especially with the "pictures" tag.

My source code look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  
import xml.sax
import re
from cStringIO import StringIO

class MovieHandler( xml.sax.ContentHandler ):
   def __init__(self):
      self.item = {}
      self.CurrentData = ""
      self.url = ""
      self.description = ""
      self.price = ""
      self.picture = ""



   # Call when an element starts
   def startElement(self, tag, attributes):
      self.CurrentData = tag
      if tag == "picture":
         print "found"
         print attributes["picture_url"]
      if tag == "ad":
         if self.item:

   # Call when an elements ends
   def endElement(self, tag):
      elif self.CurrentData == "url":
          self.item["url"] = self.url
      elif self.CurrentData == "pictures":
           self.item["picture"] = self.picture
      print self.item
      self.item.clear()

   # Call when a character is read
   def characters(self, content):
      if self.CurrentData == "url":
         self.url = content
      elif self.CurrentData == "picture":
         self.picture = content


if ( __name__ == "__main__"):

   # create an XMLReader
   parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
   # turn off namepsaces
   parser.setFeature(xml.sax.handler.feature_namespaces, 0)

   # override the default ContextHandler
   Handler = MovieHandler()
   parser.setContentHandler(Handler)

   parser.parse("myfile.xml")
```

the content tag look like this:

```
<pictures>
        <picture><picture_url><![CDATA[picture.jpg]]></picture_url></picture>
        <picture><picture_url><![CDATA[picture.jpg]]></picture_url></picture>
        <picture><picture_url><![CDATA[picture.jpg]]></picture_url></picture>
        <picture><picture_url><![CDATA[picture.jpg]]></picture_url></picture>
</pictures>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In this fragment, `<picture><picture_url>...`, `picture_url` isn't an attribute of `picture`. `picture_url` is an element. So looking for `attributes["picture_url"]` makes no sense.

Either rewrite your XML so that `picture_url` is an attribute:

```
<picture picture_url="picture.jpg></picture>
```

or rewrite your code to look for the content of `picture_url`, not `picture`.

Also, inside `characters`, realize that text doesn't have to be delivered in one call. It might come in fits and spurts. Collect it using `+=`, like so:

```
# Call when a character is read
def characters(self, content):
  ...
     self.url += content
  ...
```

Of course, you'll need to clear `self.url` when you are done with it.